# Integrating equation using scipy

Tags: python, scipy

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integrand(a, b):
    return a * x ** 2 + b

a = 2
b = 1

I = quad(integrand, 0, 1, args=(a,b))
I
```

This is my program. When I tried to run it, it was showing error :

```
integrand () takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given ....
```

I didn't understand why it is asking for 3 arguments when there are only two variables, i.e. `a` and `b`.

Can anyone help me? Can anyone clarify my doubts?

Comment: Did any of the below answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Just replace

```
def integrand(a, b):
```

by

```
def integrand(x, a, b):
```

The problem is that in the function, you use a variable `x` but you do not pass the variable `x` as an argument to the function. `0` and `1` acts as the limits of the integral but since you are integrating w.r.t. `x`, you get this error.

**Output**

```
(1.6666666666666667, 1.8503717077085944e-14)
```

Answer (score 2):

`a*x**2+b` This function you are using contain a variable `x`, in your case `def integrand(a, b):`  does not contain a variable x which uses 0 to 1 limits of the integral you are using on `I=quad(integrand,0,1,args=(a,b))`.

So all you have to do is add `x` to your def;

```
def integrand(x, a, b):    
    return a * x ** 2 + b

a = 2    
b = 1    
I = quad(integrand,0,1,args=(a,b))    
I
```